# compiler-plugin error on pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

this is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WarSpringMVCSample</groupId>
  <artifactId>WarSpringMVCSample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      **<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>**
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

this is my issue: i got error 
---->this line
        maven-compiler-plugin

please help if knows

thanks advanced

Comment: You have the plugin defined twice.

Comment: Please past the full error message into the post. Furthermore why do you changed the default locations?

Comment: @khmarbaise i guess he uses eclipse/m2e, which sets the `srcDirectory` when you convert the project to maven nature.